# How can I make Windows download updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, download, updates, mobile-hotspot

My internet connection is my phone - my laptop connects via its hotspot.

I have allowed Windows to download updates over metered connections and updates are not paused.

It says "Updates are available but they are too big to download over your current connection.". The update in question was KB5004237 - 2021-07 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 2004 for x64-based Systems, but I expect the problem is not restricted to just one.

Under advanced options I have tried flicking the switch to allow updates on metered connections back and forth, pausing, unpausing and I have tried restarting. Same result. Does anybody know how I can persuade Windows to download updates or even do that manually?

Comment: Yes, you can download it manually. What specific update is it?

Comment: Ah, I just discovered and did it - thank you!

Comment: An easier solution could be to just tell Windows it’s not a metered connection.

Comment: That didn't work in this case.

Comment: What updates exactly are you being are to large?

Comment: If you mean size - it was ~0.5GB.

Comment: @nsandersen - I am asking which updates specifically were to large?  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer is going to https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ and searching for the update code in question, for instance `KB5004237`.

Then searching for the precise title mentioned in Windows Update to find the right file on the [page](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5004237), `2021-07 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 2004 for x64-based Systems`, downloading the file manually and opening/installing it.

Then to verify after restarting - pause/unpause updates to make Windows check for new updates and realise that this one has now been installed.

I will leave the question open to see if somebody have a better idea, however.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.
Download this windows update tool.

https://www.wureset.com/files/installers/wureset11009_setup_winx64.exe

Select the 6th option ,which is the system file check tool.
This tool will take at least 5 minutes to run. My windows update allowed me to update after running this tool when I was connected to my 4g hotpot on my android phone.

If you problem is still not solved, then you can go ahead and run the 2nd option in the tool which 'resets the windows update components'.

This is a late reply.Hope this helps any other wary traveler.